# Filtering an array of dictionaries

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of dictionary liker this ..
I have to create an array which contain all key where search key matches or contain "builder_name" key value

```
"data": [
    {
        "Websiteuser": {
            "builder_name": "Mahagun India Pvt Ltd "
        },
        "MessageBoardAppusersAlls": {
            "id": "68",
            "message": "Fairpockets is a concept which has originated to not only provide fair priced properties but also allow only fair or trusted builders to list their properties on our website.",
            "created": "2018-07-23 14:24:52"
        },
        "Appusermessages": {
            "status": "1"
        },
        "Project": {
            "project_name": "Mahagun Mantra II"
        }
    },
    {
        "Websiteuser": {
            "builder_name": "Mahagun India Pvt Ltd "
        },
        "MessageBoardAppusersAlls": {
            "id": "69",
            "message": "In the current market anybody can list or advertise properties at any price which they want. This brings confusion to both buyers and sellers and they are not able to ascertain what price to ask as a seller or what price to pay as a buyer.",
            "created": "2018-07-23 14:25:00"
        },
        "Appusermessages": {
            "status": "1"
        },
        "Project": {
            "project_name": "Mahagun Mantra Villaments"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: what u tried so far

Comment: let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "builder_name CONTAINS[C] %@", String(searchText))
        let array = (mainArray as NSArray).filtered(using: searchPredicate)

Comment: And did you get any error with that code (that you should put on the question with an edit)? Note that you are missing a level: "Websiteuser". So it should at least be `(format: "Websiteuser .builder_name CONTAINS[C]...`

Comment: @Pritam Please update your question with the code you've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

The challenge is that the key `builder_name` is in another dictionary for key `Websiteuser`.

Don't *`predicate`*, `filter` with a closure

```
let query = "India"
let filteredArray = mainArray.filter { (dictionary) -> Bool in
    guard let webSiteUser = dictionary["Websiteuser"] as? [String:String],
        let builderName = webSiteUser["builder_name"] else { return false }
    return builderName.range(of: query, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
}
```

The equivalent of `CONTAINS[C]` is `range(of: options: .caseInsensitive) != nil`